# Rails partial taking too much time to render sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, partial-views, renderpartial

In my views, I am rendering a partial. This is actually a row element that shows up in a table some 500 - 600 times. I have eager loaded all associations. 
But, the issue is, same partial takes abruptly different render-time some times.

My rails server o/p:

```
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (1330.3ms)
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (4.8ms)
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (4.8ms)
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (8.8ms)
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (4.4ms)
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (1309.9ms)
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (4.7ms)
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (4.6ms)
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (4.6ms)
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (1322.6ms)
Rendered admin/invoices/_update.html.erb (4.2ms)
```

Also, there is no particular row that takes longer every time.

In my view file:

```
<% @updates.each do |update| %>
<%= render :partial => 'update', :locals => {:user => update[0]} #each of this is  a row %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:
Also suggest if this a good way to do this? i.e: looping over a partial so many times. I can't use pagination and Ajax to fasten up things.! Any other approach.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I'm not sure why the lag spikes in the rendering, i strongly recomend inverting the order: You give all the updates to the partial and inside it you iterate and render the rows.

In view file

```
    <%= render :partial => 'update', :locals => {:updates => @updates} %>
```

And inside the update partial

```
    <% updates.each do |update| %>
       RENDER LOGIC
    <% end %>
```

This why you don't suffer the partial loading overhead for every row in your update. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I tried this, and the render is instantly down by roughly 15% - 20%. However still couldn't understand the reason for those irregular spikes.

Comment: Are your results from a development enviroment? Keep in mind that in production, views code is cached, so maybe the other suggestion could make more sense performance-wise. Try making your benchmark in a production enviroment, as those are the rendering times that will matter in the end.

Comment: Enabled asset pipelining, precompiled the assets and whoa, the page shoot up right there! lightening fast! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Partials are very useful in rendering collections. When you pass a collection to a partial via the :collection option, the partial will be inserted once for each member in the collection:

```
<%= render :partial => 'update', :collection => @updates %>
```

There is also a shorthand for this. Assuming @updates is a collection of update instances, you can simply write this in the index.html.erb to produce the same result:

```
<%= render @updates %>
```

[Section 3.4.5 of the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) explains this in detail.